# How to resolve ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized?

Tags: java, azure, iot

I am trying to get the list of devices from azure IOT by using JAVA REST API.
when I use this URL

```
https:iothubhostname/devices/?maxCount=5&api-version=2015-07-01
```

It's giving response as:

> ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized

Can you anyone help us, how to make this request as authorized request?

Comment: Notice that your URL is incorrect. You need to have `https://` - `https://iothubhostname/devices/?maxCount=5&api-version=2015-07-01`

Comment: Thank you Bubble Hacker. But url is not the problem.I tried with this url also (https://iothubhostname/devices/?maxCount=5&api-version=2015-07-01) . Its giving same error msg

Comment: @Bhagya did you find any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, we can know that there is something wrong with your authorization header. The following screenshot is my result:

[image]

Here is the http request details:

[image]

For how to generate Authorization header, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security). Here is a key snippet from the article:

> {signature}    An HMAC-SHA256 signature string of the form: {URL-encoded-resourceURI} + "\n" + expiry. Important: The key is decoded from base64 and used as key to perform the HMAC-SHA256 computation.

Hope this could help your.

Comment: What exactly could be wrong with authorization header?